# A simple way to make a JQueryUI Menu work regardless its contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menuitem

The first menu is OK, since it's just a div. No matter where its clicked, it works. The second one, it's a div containing a link `<a>`, and only works if its clicked right it the link, but I'd like to make it work when clicked in the extension of the menu itself, like the previous menu with the div.

How would you suggest solve this?

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <div onclick="alert('Click');">Item 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu').menu();
});
```

Comment: Add a class to the div, bind on that class, any time it is clicked, find the nested a tag and click it.

Comment: Consider looking at the `select` callback: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#event-select

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `select` callback, you can see what item was selected and perform actions based on that. There are lots of ways to accomplish this, so here is one simple example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu').menu({
    select: function(e, ui) {
      var action = $("div", ui.item).data("action");
      switch (action.split("::")[0]) {
        case "alert":
          console.log(action);
          alert(action.split("::")[1]);
          break;
        case "link":
          console.log(action);
          window.open(action.split("::")[1], '_blank');
          break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <div data-action="alert::Click">Item 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-action="link::index.html">Home</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can also select the `div` and assign `click` callback too:

```
$("#menu li div").click(function(event){});
```

This will also work in a similar manner. If there is a child `a`, then you can pull the `href` attribute and perform some action.

Hope that helps.